# Spring bean creation property not writable exception while migrating to jre 1.8

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I am getting the below exception while creating the bean of `HazelCast`. This occurs when I change the installed JRE version to `jre 1.8` . However in `jre 1.6` we do not get the error. Are there any changes made to `jre 8` that forbids the use of such configurations.

**ERROR:**

```
Invalid property 'name' of bean class [com.hazelcast.config.TopicConfig]: Bean property 'name' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

In the `setter` of the property `name` of the third party class `TopicConfig` we can see that it is returning the instance of `TopicConfig` and is not a `void` return type. Are there any changes made to `java 8` which forbids the configuration of such type where setters are returning something

Comment: What's your Spring version? It looks like an already fixed issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8079

Comment: I have done the above changes using 2 different spring versions 2.5.6 and 4.0.0. In both the cases I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer but is to show code sample.**

I tried following (Java 1.8.0_181, Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE), it's constructing topic bean without an issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
  ITopic topic = context.getBean("topic", ITopic.class);
}
```

`spring.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.10.xsd">

  <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:interface>127.0.0.1</hz:interface>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>

        <hz:topic name="my-topic" />
    </hz:config>
  </hz:hazelcast>

  <hz:topic id="topic" instance-ref="instance" name="my-topic" />

</beans>
```